# Animate shapes / smart objects in PSD file using data/variable csv input

Tags: csv, data-visualization, photoshop, export-to-csv, psd

I'm creating a data infographic in Photoshop that inputs 'strengths / weaknesses' from a .csv file in Excel. The only thing I'd like to have is the bars that signal strength/weaknesses to adjust to the data in the csv (e.g. get longer/shorter).

To make it more clear-
Student test scores > .csv file > .psd graphic variables > if A1 = >80%, A1 psd graphic is bigger.

Essentially, I don't want to have to use illustrator to actually 'animate' the graphics. I'm wondering if there's an easier way to have flexible moving graphics per every different .csv data variable.

Would it be easier to just set each graphic itself as a pixel variable that changes? I'm hoping not. Solutions? Anyone have a script for something like this?

Answer (score 0):

A script would be the best answer to your task, if you want to avoid a photoshop variable per pixel graphic.
I am mostly experienced with variable data using Illustrator, but I believe same can be accomplished with photoshop. In your case, variables would be wholly unnecessary, as you'll simply need a script which changes the drawing of your artwork based on CSV data. For example, you can have pixel or path layers named by column headers, and the script would draw or change the path shape according to the data. To get help with such a custom script, you may reach out in the Adobe Scripting forums.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was assuming just as much but wasn't aware of the Adobe Scripting forum-- I'm going to head over there now to have them review my script.